# ElementTree parsing the next tag in Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have XML of the format:

```
<id>33000</id>
<url>www.google.com</url>
<tag>website</tag>
```

However, sometimes there are multiple tags, for example:

```
<id>33000</id>
<url>www.google.com</url>
<tag>website</tag>
<tag>search</tag>
```

The code I have is as follows:

```
tree = ET.parse('unified.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.findall('object'):
    tag = child.find('tag').text
    print tag
```

However, this way I can't seem to print the second tag, i.e., "search". Is there a way to check whether there are multiple values of tags with the same name and print/get all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same as you do for root tag?

```
tree = ET.parse('unified.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.findall('object'):
    for tag in child.findall('tag'):
        print tag.text
```